# Simple CUDA app, cudaMalloc ends with Error: unspecified driver error

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm a newbie with CUDA so be patient with me please. I have a simple VS2012 project with one main.cpp file with the following source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*CUDA*/
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    /*Device Variables*/
    uchar3 *Image_dev;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Image_dev,64*48*sizeof(uchar3));
    printf("Error:\t%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));

    return(0);
}
```

It runs without any fatal errors, but the cudaGetLastError() writes out an error "unspecified driver error" and I have no clue why. What am I doing wrong?

I have GeForce GT 740m with the latest driver installed. I have installed CUDA 6.0.
I configured all the includes and linkings. I add **cudart.lib** to Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.

I also set the following things:

Project Configuration->VC++ Directoties->Executable Directories the $(CUDA_BIN_PATH)

Project Configuration->VC++ Directoties->Include Directories the $(CUDA_INC_PATH)

Project Configuration->VC++ Directoties->Library Directories the $(CUDA_LIB_PATH)

Project Configuration->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories->$(CUDA_LIB_PATH)

I also set the compute_30 and sm_30.

What I'm doing wrong?

Regards,

Robert

Comment: Have you tried running cuda-memcheck to see if there is a bad pointer issue?

Comment: No, I didn't. But I don't know how to run it? Any hint or link please.

Comment: I tried to run the Cuda Debugging with memcheck but it fails with following message:
A CUDA context was created using API version 3010. Debugging requires API version 3020. Update the attached process to use a newer version of the CUDA API.

Comment: You may have a mismatched machine configuration, or a mismatched project configuration.  Did you have CUDA toolkits prior to CUDA 6.0 installed?  Are you able to run the `deviceQuery` CUDA sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I already solve my problem and I don't really understand the solution, and it maybe because of some mismatched configuration like Robert Crovella said. I have installed CUDA 5.5 and CUDA 6.0 too, but I had set up the 6.0 toolkit. So I don't know exactly what could be the problem.

But my solution was:
I just create a brand new CUDA project and there was everything working fine so I went thru the configurations and I set up my project like that CUDA project and it started to work when I add to Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies these libraries

> kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib
>   advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib
>   odbccp32.lib

what I don't understand because all of these libraries was already in the Inherited values.
But it started to work. If anybody know, why was it needed to add those libraries manually, post it please.